# How did K know Deckard was being transported to the airport?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

Toward the end of Blade Runner 2049, Officer K decides to attempt to rescue Deckard from Wallace's control. Deckard is being transported to the airport on Wallace's behalf by Luv when K intercepts them.

**How did K know where to find Deckard?**

Earlier in the film, at least two other locating strategies are revealed. I think neither would be relevant to K at this time in the story:

1. First, Luv is able to locate K, when he is in Las Vegas looking for Deckard, using Lt. Joshi's computer. But access to this system is restricted (Luv uses Joshi's face to unlock it). K is a rogue Blade Runner and told by Joshi that he will have 48 hours before he is hunted. I think it's safe to imply that a rogue Blade Runner would have access revoked to restricted systems. Additionally, if the system could be used to find Deckard, I think Luv or Wallace would have used it to find Deckard directly. They already knew he existed and were looking for him (as were others). This didn't happen during the film timeline, or before it, so I think the system on Joshi's computer can't locate Deckard.
2. Second, Marietta and the replicant rebels are able to locate K using a tracker planted on K earlier. We never see K plant a similar tracker device on Deckard, so I think he shouldn't be able to track him this way.

Comment: He doesn't know, he finds out. He's a detective remember? And a decent one at that.

Answer (score 4):

## He tails them from Wallace's tower

After his scene with the giant "Joi", K decides to go after Luv and Deckard:

> No answers from “Joi.” Only a knowing wink and her mannequin
> smile as she looks back out on the city. Selling herself to
> the world.
> CLOSE ON K. His eyes close. As if saying goodbye. To her.
> To everything he learned from her to dream and hope for.
> His eyes open on the sky as lightning kindles. A storm. A
> decision made.
> He fingers DECKARD’S BLASTER. And we --
>
> CUT TO:
>
> EXT. WALLACE TOWER. NIGHT.
> A WALLACE CORP TRANSPORT VAN LIFTS OFF from the platform.
> TWO DARK, SLEEK SPINNERS lift off after and follow after.
> A moment, then... K’S SPINNER’S LIGHTS COME ON. Waiting in
> the wings, barely noticeable. It follows after --
>
> EXT. SKIES ABOVE LOS ANGELES. NIGHT.
> THE TRANSPORT VAN flies through the FOG and WET SNOW.
> Flanked by THE TWO DARK SPINNERS.
> <sup>*-Blade Runner 2049, Final Shooting Script, Fancher, H. and Green, M. 2017.*</sup>

You can see that he goes to Wallace's Tower, sees Luv and the other two flanking transporters taking off, and tails them.

He's a detective after all, and it looks like he's a good one at that!